# How to remove duplicate key value array in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array I want to remove array if it value are same from others

```
$appointments = array(
                      array('1','Monday', '5:30 PM'),
                      array('2','Friday', '6:00 PM'),
                      array('3','Monday', '5:30 PM'),
                      array('4','Tuesday', '4:15 PM'),
                      array('5','Wednesday', '8:30 PM'),
                      array('6','Thursday', '1:45 PM')
);
```

I want this result **Monday** and time is display two time so I have to display only one time I use below code for this so please provide better solution for this

```
$one_dimension = array_map('serialize', $appointments);
$unique_one_dimension = array_unique($one_dimension);
$unique_multi_dimension = array_map('unserialize', $unique_one_dimension);

echo "<pre>";print_r($unique_multi_dimension);
```

Comment: so, which array are you going to remove/keep? the first ore the last? which values are important here - only second elements or first and thirds are also?

Comment: `$appointments = array_intersect_key($appointments, array_unique(array_column($appointments, 1)));`

Comment: any one but make sure duplicate will not display

Comment: I would use array key, go to the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734844/display-values-of-array-with-the-same-key-together. If you need help, just ask

Comment: Hello @MarkBaker its working only because u have use array_column but we have to compare both value week days and time also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/774206)

```
<?php

$appointments = array(
                      array('1','Monday', '5:30 PM'),
                      array('2','Friday', '6:00 PM'),
                      array('3','Monday', '5:30 PM'),
                      array('4','Tuesday', '4:15 PM'),
                      array('5','Wednesday', '8:30 PM'),
                      array('6','Thursday', '1:45 PM')
);
//Here we are finding column of week days.


$implodedColumns=  array_map(function($data){
    unset($data[0]);
    return implode(",", array_map('trim', $data));
}, $appointments);
$result=array_unique($implodedColumns); 

array_walk($result, function(&$value,$key){
    $value=  array_merge(array($key),  explode(",", $value));
});

print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => Monday
            [2] => 5:30 PM
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Friday
            [2] => 6:00 PM
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => Tuesday
            [2] => 4:15 PM
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => Wednesday
            [2] => 8:30 PM
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => Thursday
            [2] => 1:45 PM
        )

)
```

Comment: hello but we dont have to compare only week days we have to compare weekdays  and time also

Comment: @ErNilayParekh Sorry that was a mistake. You can check now

Comment: hello @sahil-gulati u provide sollution is working on this example but in my case there is tomany colums available so how can i compare?

Comment: @ErNilayParekh Can you provide a sample of that array.?

Comment: there are chat option available ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141516/discussion-between-er-nilay-parekh-and-sahil-gulati).

Answer (score 1):

```
$one_dimension = array_map('serialize', $appointments);
$unique_one_dimension = array_unique($one_dimension);
$unique_multi_dimension[1] = array_map('unserialize', $unique_one_dimension);

echo "<pre>";print_r($unique_multi_dimension);die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard O(n^2) generic cloning solution:

```
function array_unique_callback($array, $equalityComparer) {
    $uniqueFiltered = [];
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i++) {
         $add = true;
         for ($j = 0;$j < $i;$j++) {
              if ($equalityComparer($array[$keys[$i]], $array[$keys[$j]])) {
                   $add = false;
                   break;
              }
         } 
         if ($add) { 
             $uniqueFiltered[] = $array[$keys[$i]]; 
         }
    }
    return $uniqueFiltered;
}
array_unique_callback($appointments, function ($x,$y) {
     return $x[1] == $y[1] && $x[2] == $y[2];
});
```

Example: 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8013c36b78d24f08651b05375d686c9e07c75a49

If you want a more optimized version:

```
function array_unique_callback($array, $comparer) {
   //Comparer is not an equality comparer, it returns negative if $x less than $y, 0 if they are equal and 1 if $x greater than $y
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    uasort($array, $comparer);
    $uniqueFiltered = [];
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($array);$i++) {
        $uniqueFiltered[$keys[$i]] = $array[$keys[$i]]; 
        while ($i < count($array) && $comparer($array[$keys[$i]],$array[$keys[$i+1]]) === 0) { $i++; }
    }
    return $uniqueFiltered;
}
```

However the second version needs you to decide on a way to compare and order each element (which is not always possible).

Answer (score -1):

@Er Nilay Parekh you can do it like below concept:

```
<?php
  $appointments = array(
                      array('1','Monday', '5:30 PM'),
                      array('2','Friday', '6:00 PM'),
                      array('3','Monday', '5:30 PM'),
                      array('4','Tuesday', '4:15 PM'),
                      array('5','Wednesday', '8:30 PM'),
                      array('6','Thursday', '1:45 PM')
);
$isTimeExist = array();
foreach ($appointments as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value[2], $isTimeExist)){
        unset($appointments[$key]);
    }
    $isTimeExist[] = $value[2];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($appointments));
```

Comment: i don't like users who down vote to any one without any explanation